# Outlook mail item multiple restrict methods

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-filter

I am trying to apply a filter using the restrict method of mail items using Outlook VBA. Below code works fine if I use only one restrict method based on Category_Filter variable, but when I try to use two restrict methods,

Somehow my Flag_Filter fails.

I believe I am making some mistake in concatenation for Flag_Filter and need some clue here.

```
Sub ApplyFilters()
Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim ns As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim fol As Outlook.Folder
Dim i As Object
Dim mi As Outlook.MailItem

Dim OrderNumber, Category_Filter, Flag_Filter As String

Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Set ns = ol.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set fol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)


OrderNumber = "GCU5689"

Category_Filter = "[Categories] = 'Textile'"
Flag_Filter = "[FlagRequest] = " & OrderNumber


For Each i In fol.Items.Restrict(Category_Filter).Restrict(Flag_Filter)

 ' Some actions

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*like @Dmitry Streblechenko says use [And Operator (Visual Basic) MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/and-operator) with your [Outlook restrict method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Items.Restrict)*

*Example*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Examples()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim Items As Outlook.Items
    Dim Msg As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Filter As String

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    Filter = "[Categories] = 'Textile' And [FlagRequest] = 'Follow up'"

    Set Items = Inbox.Items.Restrict(Filter)

    Msg = Items.Count & " Items in " & Inbox.Name

    If MsgBox(Msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
        For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
            Debug.Print Items(i) 'Immediate Window
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

[*More examples here*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A4539709%20%5Boutlook-filter%5D)

*for variable you can use the `chr(34)` function to represent the double quote (whose ASCII character value is 34) that is used as an escape character or use double quote.*

*Example*

> ```
> Dim OrderNumber As String
> OrderNumber = "GCU5689"    
> Filter = "[Categories] = 'Textile' And [FlagRequest] = '" & OrderNumber & "'"
> ```

Comment: Hi 0m3r, In my case I am ok with a constant value "Textile" for the [Categories] but the [FlagRequest] which is representing order number is being pulled from a mail merge document. Actually, I am using this code inside a mail merge document which is relying on email flagging information from Outlook and comparing order number mail merge field with FlagRequest value of the filtered email. This is kinda complicated but this is what I am doing. So, coming back to your solution, how would you alter your Filter to use a variable for FlagRequest instead of a constant? I hope you get my point.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot restrict a restricted collection. You need to combine the restrictions (using "and" ) into a single query and call `Restrict` only once.

Comment: Thank you both of you guys. Niton, your suggestion works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

In general you may apply multiple actions one at a time. Such an approach allows easier troubleshooting.

```vb
Option Explicit ' Consider this mandatory
' Tools | Options | Editor tab
' Require Variable Declaration

Sub ApplyFilters()

Dim ns As NameSpace
Dim fol As folder

Dim i As Object
Dim mi As MailItem

Dim resItms As Items

Dim OrderNumber  As String
Dim Category_Filter As String
Dim Flag_Filter As String

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set fol = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

OrderNumber = "GCU5689"

Category_Filter = "[Categories] = 'Textile'"
Flag_Filter = "[FlagRequest] = " & OrderNumber

Set resItms = fol.Items.Restrict(Category_Filter)
Debug.Print "Items after first  restrict: " & resItms.Count

Set resItms = resItms.Restrict(Flag_Filter)
Debug.Print "Items after second restrict: " & resItms.Count

For Each i In resItms

    ' Some actions

    ' If, for instance, a property is only found on mailitems
    If i.Class = olmail Then
        Set mi = i
        Debug.Print mi.Subject
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Niton, As mentioned code works fine, however, there are certain looked-up emails that meet both criteria but they go undetected by the filters. Again, these are only a few orders which are giving me problem.

Comment: Could you please think of any such reason which is causing this issue. I have checked each such undetected email and found they are marked by both criteria, i.e. categorised and flagged.

Comment: I can suggest trying one restrict then the other to see if both fail separately. You could try a new question post with the results and your current code.

Comment: Hi Niton, exactly as you say, I do not get a record skipping problem for categories, the skipping problem occurs only with FlagRequest.

Comment: You could ask a new question about why the `FlagRequest` restrict skips items.